# Improving embedding similarity search of aggregated embeddings

Tags: open-ai, embeddings, large-language-models

I am building an author suggestion tool that proposes authors writing about similar topics as a given input text. I want to use embeddings for this. The way I currently do it is to store embeddings of many articles of many different authors in a vector database. Then I generate an embedding for every author by taking the embeddings of their last X articles and calculate the mean of those vectors. I can then compare the embedding of any given input text with the aggregated author embeddings using cosine similarity.

This does work to some extend but it looks like:

1. The aggregated author embeddings do not only capture topics, but also other things such as writing style, language, and so on. Which I am not really intested in.
2. By using a mean as embedding it captures the broad field of an author quite well (e.g. tech, science, economy, sports) but the sub-fields seem to get over-shadowed by authors that write more generic articles sometimes. Searching for a niche topic often doesn't give the best results as the niche authors that wrote articles about it often get scored worse than authors that write more generic articles in the same overacrching field.

I am looking for ways to improve my method, any suggestions are welcome.